# more information on React lifecycle methods

Tags: reactjs

I'm actually working on React and I want to consolidate my knowledge on it. 
Starting with lifecycle methods:

- getDefaultProps:
  properties from both getDefaultProps and parent are consolidate here in this.props like that properties now are ready to be consumed by "getInitialState"
- getInitialState:
  this.props are used to set the state of the component. The component is now ready to be render
- componentWillMount:
  what can we do inside ?
- render:
  self explain
- componentWillMount:
  we can do some actions to clean the component

componentWillMount seems overkill ?
What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

State modification in componentWillMount will not cause additional rendering, so, it is a place for additional state initialization based on passed props. This article describes lifecycle methods: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

P.S. And one more article on state initialization, that could be useful, since you mentioned initializing state from props: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes your bullet after `render` was meant to be `componentDidMount`.

The big difference between the two

- `componentWillMount` is called before the component renders. Anything that needs to be done before rendering should exist in this function (initial calls to retrieve data, initialization of internal structures, etc.).
- `componentDidMount` is called after the component has rendered. Since the component is now added to the DOM tree, any additional DOM manipulation can be performed. Perhaps fire off events notifying the rest of the app that the component is rendered or add the element into a non-React DOM tree.